# Can C++20 concept be used to avoid hiding template function from base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to use template specialization to query component of a derive object.

The code below works fine.

However, I am new to C++.
I am not sure if such compiler behavior is reliable, and want some confirmation.

```
#include <type_traits>
class B{
   public: template<class T> T* get() requires std::is_same_v< T, B>{ //... [X]
       return this;  
   }
};
class C : virtual public B{
   public: using B::get;
   public: template<class T> T* get() requires std::is_same_v< T, C>{ //... [Y]
       return this;
   }
};
int main(){
   C c;
   B* b1=c.get<B>();
   C* c1=c.get<C>();
   B* b2=c.get<B>();
}
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition)
, even I use `using B::get`,

> If the derived class already has a member (Y) with the same **name**,
> **parameter list**, and **qualifications**, the derived class member hides or
> overrides (doesn't conflict with) the member (X) that is introduced from
> the base class.

I tried to digest the quote.

Please confirm these 3 statements.

- [X]&[Y] has the same **name** AND **parameter list**.
- But **qualification** of [X] and [Y] are difference.
- Thus, no hides or overrides occur.

Are they all correct?
If so, I will rely on this awesome behavior.

Comment: Not qualifications, but yes, remember that the templated functions are created at the first call site so they are not the same. See https://cppinsights.io/s/10b8754d. The commentary is likely helpful to you.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe  :: What is this?  It is so cool!

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need to use `std::is_same_v` in a requires statement. You can just use the `std::same_as` concept like `template<std::same_as<B> T> T* get() { return this; }`.

Comment: @Jakob Stark ::  Thank.  I never know about this concise technique.

Comment: As an aside, it is kind of unusual to have a template parameter and then restrict it to a single possible value. How about non-templates `get_B()` and `get_C()`?

Comment: @BoP ::  My existing code is exactly like what you mention.   It may be just my own opinion, but I want to reduce the amount of required manual customization.  Typing `get_B()` looks tedious/uncool.  In intellisense (e.g. find all reference), `get<B>()` might also work better than `get_B()`.  I still hesitate and seek/compare for a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified in [namespace.udecl#14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/namespace.udecl#14), emphasis mine,

> When a using-declarator brings declarations from a base class into a derived class, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]), **trailing requires-clause (if any)**, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any), in a base class (rather than conflicting). Such hidden or overridden declarations are excluded from the set of declarations introduced by the using-declarator.

As to your questions,

> - [X]&[Y] has the same name AND parameter list.
> - But qualification of [X] and [Y] are difference.
> - Thus, no hides or overrides occur.

Yes, [X] and [Y] are exactally the same except for the trailing requires clause. So, no hides occur.